# Write to files using Java

Tags: java, list, file

I am trying to use lists for my first time, I have a txt file that I am searching in it about string then I must write the result of searching in new file.

Check the image attached[image]

My task is to retrieve the two checked lines of the input file to the output files.

And this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestingReport1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File test = new File("E:\\test2.txt");
    File Result = new File("E:\\Result.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(test);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("Visit Count")|| line.contains("Title")) {
           System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
}
```

What should I do?!

Edit: How can I write the result of this code into text file?
Edit2:

Now using the following code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here

    File test = new File("E:\\test2.txt");
    FileOutputStream Result = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Result.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(test);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("Visit Count")|| line.contains("Title")) {
           System.out.println(line);
           Files.write(Paths.get("E:\\Result.txt"), line.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
       }
    }
}
```

I got the result back as Visit Count:1 , and I want to get this number back as integer, Is it possible?

Comment: i mean that looks good?  Just change the if statement to... `if(line.contains("Visit Count") || line.contains("Title")) { System.out.println(line);}`

Comment: Title "Use Lists in Java" is really misleading and unclear - it could also refer to the List class in Java. Try to make your title specific.

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović I want to use lists to write back both lines in another file!

Comment: i think your little could simply talk about retrieving information from a File with scanner, because i don't know why List is the big man here, unless you want to store the information in a List and retrieve later, simple the tittle is big for it

Comment: You don't use a list to write data to a file. Lists are only structures used in running programms. And for writing data to a file there are a lot of tutorials in the internet. Maybe searching something like "Java writing data to a file" helps you?

Comment: Sarah you're very close, you just need to change `System.out.println` to some `writeToFile`-style call, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), especially [`readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) as well as [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). Filter the input between those two method calls, that's it:

```
// Read.
List<String> input = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("E:\\test2.txt"));
// Filter.
String output = input.stream()
        .filter(line -> line.matches("^(Title.*|Visit Count.*)"))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
// Write.
Files.write(Paths.get("E:\\Result.txt"), output.getBytes());
```